# Extracting data from response.Content.ReadStringASync

Tags: c#, web-services, dotnet-httpclient

I am currently trying to extract data from my Web Service. I managed to get success response from the Web Service using HTTPClient. However, I am unable to extract specific values. For instance, my JSON document read as

`{"d":[{"__type":"Info:#website.Model","infoClosingHours":"06:00:00 PM","infoID":1,"infoOpeningDays":"Monday","infoOpeningHours":"09:00:00 AM","infoStatus":"Open"}]}`

I want to get the infoOpeningDays, however, I am unable to do it.

I tried using

```
dynamicObject.GetType().GetProperty("infoOpeningDays").GetValue(dynamicObject, null); 

dynamicObject["infoOpeningDays"];
```

But it kept giving me null.

Here's my code

```
private async void GetData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("ip");

            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            try{
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("WebServices/information.svc/GetInformationJSON").Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    dynamic dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
                    //string abc = dynamicObject.IEnumerator.[0].IEnumerator.[0].IEnumerator.[0].IEnumerator.[5].Name;
                    string abc = dynamicObject.GetType().GetProperty("infoOpeningDays").GetValue(dynamicObject, null);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access the properties directly from your dynamic object like this:

```
dynamic dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
string infoClosingHours = dynamicObject.d[0].infoClosingHours;
```

Or this is the same

```
string infoClosingHours = dynamicObject.d[0]["infoClosingHours"];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Extract selected attribute from Json**

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();     
var result = JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("createdDate").ToString();
// result will give the createdDate in string format.
```